# MongoDB Find based on contents of a collection in the record

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a collection of User being stored in MongoDB

Given an invoice number, how would I query the User collection to get the associated user?
(Find user in collection where Payments contains record with InvoiceNumber = '###')

```
public class User
{
[BsonId]
public ObjectId ID { get; set; }
public string UserName {get;set;}
public List<PaymentInfo> Payments {get;set;} 
}

public class PaymentInfo
{
public string CardNumber {get;set;}
public int InvoiceNumber {get;set;}
public float Amount {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are transparent to MongoDB. So

```
db.yourCollection.find({Payments.InvoiceNumber: 1234})
```

should return all documents where the payments array contains one or more objects where InvoiceNumner = 1234.

Comment: +1, but shouldn't that be `db.yourCollection.find({'Payments.InvoiceNumber': 1234})`?

Comment: The quotes are optional, AFAIK.

Comment: Not if this is a shell example.  Same goes for the `=` instead of a `:`